# Trying to write a conditional statement where +1 is added for each condition met in statement in a summed new column

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am trying to write an if/else statement where if each condition is met +1 is added to a new column named total_condition and the result is a column with the summed +1's from each condition
it seems simple but I cannot figure it out, please help if you can :)
this is my first time posting.

Example of what is not working:

```
DF1 <- DF1 %>%
   mutate(total_condition = ifelse((v1 %in% c(2,4), 1,
                            if else(v2 >= 3, +1,
                                    if else(v3 <=2, +1, 0)))))
```

*please ignore any bracket errors
this code only returns a column with 1 and 0's

I have also tried:

```
 DF1 <- DF1 %>%
       mutate(total_condition = ifelse((v1 %in% c(2,4), 1,
                                if else(v2 >= 3, 1 + total_condition,
                                        if else(v3 <=2, 1 + total_condition, 0)))))
```

This returned error saying unused arguments.

Comment: It would help if you can update your post to include (1) example data (can be small), (2) current output and/or error messages, (3) desired output that matches your example data

Comment: Multiple `ifelse()` is a bad idea. Consider `dplyr::case_when()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're wanting something like this:

```
DF1 |> dplyr::mutate(total_condition = (v1 %in% c(2,4)) + 
                                       (v2 >= 3) + 
                                       (v3 <=2),
              total_condition = cumsum(total_condition))

# or with base R:
DF1$total_condition <- (DF1$v1 %in% c(2,4)) + (DF1$v2 >= 3) + (DF1$v3 <=2)
DF1$total_condition <- cumsum(DF1$total_condition)
```

Output:

```
   v1 v2 v3 total_condition
1   9  5  5               1
2   4 10  5               3
3   7  6  2               5
4   1 10 10               6
5   2  7  9               8
6   7  9  1              10
7   2  5  4              12
8   3  5  3              13
9   1  9  6              14
10  5  9 10              15
```

Data:

```
set.seed(0)

DF1 <- data.frame(
    v1 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
    v2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
    v3 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```